# Timepicker: how to change second value by change on first?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a agenda application in PHP, Bootstrap and Angular JS.
See Plunker for live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/FSXB9IvGWOMgFzuEASEl?p=preview

Now If i want to change the "start time" with an additional hour, I want the "end time" to change also +1 hour. (so that the interval is always 1 hour minimum when changing the start time.) ofcourse, when changing the "end time" it doesn't matter if the gap is bigger than 1 hour.

I want something like this:

```js
$scope.updateTimeEnd = function() {
   $scope.TimeEnd.setHours($scope.TimeStart.getHours() + 1);
 };
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="selectStartTime">
      <timepicker ng-model="TimeStart" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="selectEndTime">
      <timepicker ng-model="TimeEnd" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<timepicker>` element is included in this js file:`<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>`

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

I don't mind if it's with angular (eg. ng-bind) or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.updateTimeEnd = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours($scope.TimeStart.getHours() +1);
    //d.setMinutes($scope.TimeStart.getMinutes());
    $scope.TimeEnd = d;
};

$scope.$watch('TimeStart', function() {
    $scope.updateTimeEnd();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Giannis, When adding this function to my js file it still does nothing.

Comment: @KevinRovers if you place it on your Plunker example (dateTime.js), and press the up/down button on your start time hour picker on the bottom, you will see both TimeStart/End dates updated on the "Selected date" top label.

Comment: thanks for your comment, But I want the hour selector on the right to change value, The box on the top is only to see the outcome. I added it to the plunker example.

Comment: @KevinRovers just updated the answer for your scenario. The commented-out line can be used to follow the minutes as well.